# Problem connecting with WCF service

Tags: asp.net, iis, wcf, wcf-security

**Background:**

I have a WCF service deployed on my local machine that in turns connects to the SQL Server 2005 database.

To consume the service, I have a client application that dynamically creates the service client to consume the methods exposed in wcf service.

Configuration:

```
OS: Windows XP
IIS : 5.1
```

**Problem**

When I run client **FIRST TIME** on the local machine ( where service is deployed) it fails to connect with the service.

While debugging I notice when I call any method (exposed in the service) the following error occurred (I have pasted the exception at the bottom).

Now When I go into explorer and type the address to open in the browser like:

```
https:\\localhost\\TestService\\TestService.svc.
```

it opens successfully in browser..

Now I again go the client app and try consuming the web service, it connects successfully..

Strange enough, when I re-start IIS, the problem again occurs...  To run the client app for the first time, I have to browse it in Internet Explorer.

Note: I have implemented SSL through a certificate..

**Exception occured:**

> The content type text/html of the
>   response message does not match the
>   content type of the binding
>   (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8).
>   If using a custom encoder, be sure
>   that the IsContentTypeSupported method
>   is implemented properly. The first 163
>   bytes of the response were:
>   'ErrorEither
>   a required impersonation level was not
>   provided, or the provided
>   impersonation level is invalid.

The same thing works fine in Windows 2003 server and IIS 6.0

Comment: Try first using it without security, once everything works, reconfigure security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to have good explanation of your problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/63856c25-bdfd-4773-8347-4003064dec8e/).

You should try his workaround by enabling anonymous access on IIS.

Hope this helps...